# Is there an easy way to observe the visible cells in a UITableView?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I need to keep track of the visible cells in a `UITableView`, since certain events need to occur when cells that represent specific pieces of data become visible. `UITableView` doesn't seem to be KVO compliant for `-indexPathsForVisibleRows` or `-visibleCells`, and there's no `UITableViewDelegate` method that gives a hook for being notified that the visible cells have changed.

Is there any way of doing this, short of manually keeping track of my own array, and adding/removing objects every time I insert/remove a row, reload the table, or methods like `-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` are called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without hacking/subclassing UITableView or UITableViewCell, the answer appears to be no.

Answer (score 6):

How about UITableViewDelegate method:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Comment: From what I can tell `UITableView.visibleCells` is updated _after_ this method is called, so it doesn't help solve this particular problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not doing too many exotic things with the table itself, like re-arranging and deleting/inserting rows, you could use the scrollviewDidScroll: method, and the other scrollview delegate methods that are sent by a tableview.

in that method you can call visibleCells and go from there.